# Replace text at the first of the specific lines? Sigil or Notepad++ Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, sigil

How can I replace text at the first of specific lines

Example before:

```
<p>– Your mother created a song?</p>
<p>– She was a pianist.</p>
<p>– Okay then, let us hear the song.</p>
```

And i want to be like this

```
<p>"Your mother created a song?"
<p>"She was a pianist."</p>
<p>"Okay then, let us hear the song."</p>
```

Is there a way to do it in selected text area maybe with regex?

Comment: To be clear, you want to remove the `– ` at the beginning of each line and suround all lines with quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=<p>)– (.+)(?=</p>)`
- Replace with: `"$1"`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=<p>)    # positive lookbehind, make sure we have <p> before
    –       # – character followed by a space
    (.+)    # group 1, any character nut newline
(?=</p>)    # positive lookahead, make sure we have </p> after
```

**Replacement:**

```
"   # a double quote
$1  # content of group 1, the sentence
"   # a double quote
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<p>"Your mother created a song?"</p>
<p>"She was a pianist."</p>
<p>"Okay then, let us hear the song."</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work on notepad++, but on sigil ( html) it's not work

here example text

<p>– Your mother created a song?</p>

<p>– She was a pianist.</p>

<p>– Okay then, let us hear the song.</p>

and i want like this

<p>"Your mother created a song?</p>

<p>"She was a pianist.</p>

<p>"Okay then, let us hear the song."</p>

Comment: @ArisMunandar: You've ask for a regex for Notepad++ or Sigil. I don't know sigil, may it doesn't understand regex.

Comment: sigil is like ebook (epub) editor, where you can edit ebook using html.
but it's okay now, it's worked while trying your code and with little edit. 

Thank you!

Comment: @ArisMunandar: I have updated the answer to deal with `<p>` tags.